# Processing affects current directory of Arduino environment

Tags: ide, arduino, processing

I have my processing code in dev/processing and my Arduino code put itself in Documents/Arduino.

However, whenever I get into one environment, it changes the most recent directory for the other because Arduino is written in processing.

Is there any quick way to disconnect the two environments so that they don't use the same location for "most recent directory?"  I don't know whether the mechanism is a file, a registry entry or what, but I'm on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

I am using both Arduino IDE as well as Processing 2.1.2 in Windows 7 environment. It doesn't change the directory.

Since you are using Windows 8.1 (which is recently released), you may face very weird problems as those softwares are not tested on those OS. You will find errors for even other softwares that are designed before Windows 8.

Comment: Interesting.  Why, did they change the registry in a fundamental way?